# return value with nested function using the request NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm scraping the ghost blogging platform and the package I'm using to do so is request, but I'm not sure how to return a value of a nested request. I commented out the area that is causing the issue. Thanks!

```
    var express = require('express');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var app     = express();

    app.get('/', function(req, res){

    var url = 'http://<subdomain>.ghost.io';
    var articles = [];

    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        if(!error){
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var post;

            $('article').each(function(index) {
                var self = $(this);

                var article = {
                    header : self.find('h2.post-title').text(),
                    route: url + self.find('h2.post-title a').attr('href'),
                    content : '',
                    author: self.find('footer a').text(),
                    timestamp : self.find('time.post-date').text()
                };

                request(article.route, function(error, response, html) {
                    $ = cheerio.load(html);
                    post = $('section.post-content').text();
                    return post; //*** this is what I can't return ***//
                    //*** I'd like it to be the value of article.content ***//
                });

                console.log(post); //*** undefined ***//

                articles.push(article);

            });

            fs.writeFile('posts.json', JSON.stringify(articles, null, 4), function(err){
                console.log('Posts created.');
            });

        }

    });
})


app.listen('8000');
console.log('Watching for changes.');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Where do you want to return the value to / what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem boils down to having a list of URLs, and wanting to (asynchronously, because node.js) request all of them, and then know when they've all finished and then do something with the collected results.

The [`async` module](https://github.com/caolan/async) (`npm install async`) will let you do that like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var urls = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com"];

async.map(urls, request, function(err, results) {
    // First 100 characters of http://google.com
    console.log(results[0].body.substr(0, 100));

    // First 100 characters of http://yahoo.com
    console.log(results[1].body.substr(0, 100));
});
```

So you can apply this to your problem by doing the following:

1. Synchronously create the entire `articles` list.
2. Use `async.map` on the list.
3. In the callback to `async.map`, you have a list of all the responses; you can process them synchronously.